# Variable scope in do while loop

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Ok so, I'm new to JS and Discord.js and I started to write a small discord bot last week.

I want my bot to be able to delete all messages older than 6 days in a specific channel.

The main issues I have to face are :

**1** - I can't use `message.channel.bulkDelete()` because it can't delete messages older than 14 days

**2** - `message.channel.messages.fetch()` can only fetch a maximum of 100 messages

I wrote this code :

```
    try {
    if (message.channel.id === '<TheChannelID>') {
        do {
            let TargetedMsgs = 0 // Initializing my counter of the messages that meet my date condition
            message.channel.messages.fetch().then(messages => { // fetching the messages in the channel (100 max)
                messages.forEach(message => { // loop through each message in the fetched messages
                    let Today = new Date()
                    let TargetDate = new Date(Today.setDate(Today.getDate()-6))
                    if (message.createdAt < TargetDate) { // the message is older than 6 days
                        message.delete()
                        TargetedMsgs ++ // There is at least on message that meets the condition in this fetch batch
                    }
                })
            })
        }
        while (
            TargetedMsgs > 0
        )
    }
}
catch (err){
    console.error(err)
}
```

**I get :**

```
ReferenceError: TargetedMsgs is not defined
```

**In my while condition.**

I understand why. It's because my `let TargetedMsgs` is out of scope because it's out of my `do` block.

The thing is, how can I accomplish what I want to do? Using a for loop? I don't know how to do it.

I would gladly take your advices!

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: If you declare the variable with `let` then the variable can only be visible inside the block (i.e. inside the `{` and it matching `}`). Move the declaration to outside the loop: `let TargetedMsgs = 0; do { ... } while( ... );`

Comment: Heads-up: after you fix that issue, you'll encounter another one which is that the loop always exits at the first iteration. That has to do with the fact that `fetch` is asynchronous and that `while (TargetedMsgs > 0)` is evaluated before the callback of `then` gets called, so when `while (TargetedMsgs > 0)` is reached, `while TargetedMsgs` will be `0` and the loop will exit immediately.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Thanks for your responses! Exactly, that's my issue. How can I solve this then? How can I write the code so that I continue executing what's inside my actual do block until there isn't any messages older than 6 days anymore? Maybe another type of loop? But which one? I can't think of a solution...

Comment: Can you make the function/method an `async` one?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir If I can, I don't know how... I'm still learning tho', maybe tonight I will find something... But I'm open to other ways of accomplishing what I want to do! :)

Comment: Is this code wrapped in a function?

Comment: Also, I don't know discord.js so I don't quite understand what you need to do here.

Comment: It is not wrapped in a function. I could do this yes but I don't what to do after that. I will update my question in a few hours, I'm working on something else right now. Thanks again for your help. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK so! Thanks to the help of @ibrahimmahrir who put me on the right track, I figured out how to resolve my main issue!

The thing is the `fetch()` method is **asynchronous** and I needed to wait (with the **await** operator) for it to be able to delete the targeted messages.
I also change how I filter the messages to retrieve only the ones I want.

Here is the code :

```
if (message.channel.id === config.MyChannelID) {
    try {
        let TargetedMsgsCount // Initializing my variable which I use in my do/while loop
        do {
            TargetedMsgsCount = 0
            await message.channel.messages.fetch({limit:100}).then(messages => {
                let Today = new Date()
                let TargetDate = new Date(Today.setDate(Today.getDate()-6))
                let TargetedMsgs = messages.filter(msg => msg.createdAt < TargetDate)
                TargetedMsgs.forEach(TargetedMsg => {
                    TargetedMsg.delete()
                    TargetedMsgsCount ++ // So if there is at least one message that match my date condition, there is maybe more
                })
            })
        }
        while (
            TargetedMsgsCount > 0
        )
```

With that, my loop is now OK!

I have another issue now but that was not my main question and it would be out of topic to ask here so I consider this question closed!

**Thanks again to Ibrahim if you read this!**

Answer (score 0):

You can try Const this variable,

const thing = 0;

or make it inside the block you need,

```
messages.forEach(message => { // loop through each message in the fetched messages

                    let Today = new Date()

                    let TargetedMsgs = 0

                    let TargetDate = new Date(Today.setDate(Today.getDate()-6))

                    if (message.createdAt < TargetDate) { // the message is older than 6 days
                        message.delete()

                        TargetedMsgs ++ // There is at least on message that meets the condition in this fetch batch

                    }
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your contribution. What are you thinking of with "Consting" (is that a verb?) this variable?
I would not be able to change its value if it's a const.
And in the block you show, it doesn't solve the fact that only one fetch is not sufficient to delete all the messages I want to delete.